# How many types of way to pass the value from one page to another page in asp.net server side and client side

Tags: asp.net, server-side, webmethod

I want to pass the value from one page to another page.  Some of the think I know I. E. Session,  cookies, querystring but I don't want to use it. Also I want to get the value in static method server side. But I don't know that how can I get in static server side method.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you now want to use Session, Cookies or QueryString? It would be better to explain what you're trying to achieve as then you'd get better answers

Comment: @fermin actually I want to pass the value from one page to another page in Web static method. So is there any think that I can do that.....???

Answer (score 2):

k.Soni,

I can't comment so I replied with answer.

> Why you don't want to use session, cookies and querystring ?

I thought, You got error While getting the values from session, cookies and querystring variables inside the static method. So you don't want use tat variables. Is it correct ?

If yes, that is wrong. We can get access those variables with help of HttpContext.Current. It gives you access to the current Http Context because The HttpContext.Current property is static.

**I.e**

```
//Assigning from one page
Session["Name"]="ABC";

//get the values from session variable in static method 
string name = HttpContext.Current.Session["Name"].ToString();
```

I just derived only for session, for others refer @Fermin answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways to pass values from page to page. You've mentioned that you don't want to use Session, Cookies or QueryString but not mentioned why so I will highlight a few different methods and how you retrieve their value server-side from a static method.

All of these methods use the HttpContext which has a static `.Current` property for accessing the currently executing context.

```
// Cookie
var cookieVal = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["TestCookie"].Value;

// Query String
var qString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["Test"];

// HTTP Header
var headerVal = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-my-header"];

// Form Data
var formVal = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["form-property"];

// Session Data (you may need to decorate with [WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
var session = HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionKey"];

// HTTP Context Item
// Note: This will only work if value set server side and page 2 called with Server.Transfer() rather than Response.Redirect()
var httpItem = HttpContext.Current.Items["itemKey"];
```